# Loading page with developer tools closed on safari make a bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, cross-browser, load

I'm working on a project using skrollr.js

In the beggining there is an animation and the menu is fixed on bottom.
After the animation finish, the menu turn in to absolute and after scrolled up it turned to fixed again, but on top.

The thing is: everything is working fine in all browsers with the exception of Safari.
If you load the page in safari with the developer tools opened, it works normally.
But if you load the page with the dev tools closed, the menu get bugged.

the version i'm working on is at
http://www.eurorscgbrasil.com.br/novodenovo

I just don't know what is causing this behavior.

what could I do?

Thanks

jquery coding for menu, placed inside of $(window).scroll();:

`    if(posicao < 20060){
            $('#menu').removeAttr('style');
            $('#menu, #colorlayer').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('#menu').css('bottom', 0);
            $('#colorlayer').css('top', 0);
            $('#colorlayer').css('margin-top', 0);
            $('#menu ul li a.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#menu ul li a[href="#inicio"]').addClass('active');
        }

```
    if ((posicao >= 20060) && (posicao < fix)){
        $('#menu').removeAttr('style');
        $('#menu').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('#colorlayer').css('top', '0');
    }

    if (posicao >= fix){
        $('#menu').removeAttr('style');
        $('#menu').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('#menu').css('top', 0);
    }

    if((posicao >= fix) && (posicao < 22000)){
        $('#menu ul li a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#menu ul li a[href="#oprograma"]').addClass('active');
    }`
```

Comment: any console logging in the code?

Comment: no console logging in the code

Comment: any debugger statements in the code?

Comment: the hole code is at http://eurorscgbrasil.com.br/novodenovo/wp-content/themes/novo_de_novo_theme/js/main.js

Comment: what do you mean that it's bugged? please provide more detail. It seems to work for me (Safari 6.1.1 on Mac)

Comment: if you load the page on safari with the developer tools opened, it works fine, but if you load the page with the developer tools closed, the #menu div don't go to absolute position when it should be, and after that it stays on top when it should be on bottom

Comment: I tested on a mac and it works fine... only in window's safari the bug occurs